# PHP Remove Content when date hits

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to have make a simple script which hides content when the date hits.

So when it's 03-11-2016, show the content but when the date is 03-15-2016, hide the content.

```
if(date(m-d-Y) > "03-15-2016") {
  // do stuff
}
```

Sadly the script below isn't working for some reason, any help would be nice, thanks!

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php

Comment: If you want to compare date strings, you'll need to format with year month day instead of month day year. Also, you'll need to quote your formatting parameter to the date function.

Comment: If you want compare string date format, use `Y-m-d` format. `03-15-2016` is `<` `04-15-1980`

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean the actual format string YMD, I meant year first instead of month first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` function returns a string. Comparing strings may cause some unexpected results. What you need to compare is timestamps of dates:

```
if (strtotime("now") > strtotime("03/15/2016 00:00:00")) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Note, I changed your `"03-15-2016"` to `"03/15/2016"` cause it's format, which can be parsed by `strtotime` function.

Answer (score 1):

If your wanting to maintain the same format as your current script, this will work:

```
<?php
if(strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) > strtotime("2016-1-04")) {
  // do stuff
}
?>
```

Comment: @Carl If you liked my answer, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: This will not work. strtotime("03-8-2016") is Aug 3, not Mar 8. You can't guarantee that X-Y-Z will be interpreted as M-D-Y.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: `strtotime("03-8-2016")` interprets the 03 as day and the 8 as month. I.e., given X-Y-Z, and both X and Y are less than 13, it doesn't know if you mean M-D-Y or D-M-Y.

Comment: You don't need strtotime() at all, you can compare the strings directly as long as you format them YYYYMMDD.

Answer (score 0):

think about using something like:

```
$today = time(); // time() is now (timestamp) since epoch
$hideIt = strtotime("2016-03-15"); // timestamp of date to hide stuff

if ( $today > $hideIt ) // if today is greater than the date we want to hide things
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not working because you are using parameters in a wrong order. You need to use them in order by coming first the year, month and the day:

```
if (date('Y-m-d') > '2016-03-15') {
    // do stuff
}
```